# How Do I Fetch Name and Email using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using a TextView to show Name and Email of logged in facebook user, but i really don't know How do I fetch Name and Email ?

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
                                  Exception exception) {
    if (session != currentSession) {
        return;
    }

    if (state.isOpened()) {
        // Log in just happened.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "session opened",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        // Log out just happened. Update the UI.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "session closed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need permission to get Basic Information of user Permissions.EMAIL and  Permissions.BASIC_INFO to get first name and email.

Comment: Which Facebook SDK are you using ?

Comment: @DarshanParikh thank you so much, post it as your answer...

Comment: Its Ok. You can vote up this comment if this helped.

Comment: @DarshanParikh bro but i have to accept an answer and i want to accept which i used, please post as your answer i am waiting ..

Comment: I have posted the answer. Check that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name and email as below:

```
// use their Facebook info
    JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me"));
    String facebookID = json.getString("id");
    String firstName = json.getString("first_name");
    String lastName = json.getString("last_name");
    Toast.makeText(uiActivity,"Thank you for Logging In, " 
                 + firstName + " " 
                 + lastName + "!"
                 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```