# Android getting data from facebook json

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"108303252910226","first_name":"Chris","last_name":"Jack","email":"adaptech123@gmail.com","gender":"male","birthday":"08\/08\/1984","hometown":{"id":"106377336067638","name":"Bangalore, India"}}, error: null}
```

I'm getting this response from facebook.
how to get the first name

I have tired

```
 try {
                                String res = response+"";
                                JSONObject j = new JSONObject(res);
                                String graphResponse = j.optString("graphObject");

                                JSONObject j2 = new JSONObject(graphResponse);

                                String first_name = j2.getString("first_name");

                                Log.i("firstname", ""+first_name);
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Comment: What have you done so far? post your code

Comment: Understand json object and how to use it, http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html.

Comment: This might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317540/how-do-i-fetch-name-and-email-using-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 0):

inside your GraphRequest method

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
         object.getString("first_name")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's multidimensional array so you first spilt that array.

```
String res="["+"{responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"108303252910226","first_name":"Chris","last_name":"Jack","email":"adaptech123@gmail.com","gender":"male","birthday":"08\/08\/1984","hometown":{"id":"106377336067638","name":"Bangalore, India"}}, error: null}"+"]";
            JSONObject c;
            JSONArray data=null;
            try {
                data = new JSONArray(res);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }  
      try {
         if(data != null) {
               for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                  c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                  String lat=c.getString("responseCode");
                   JSONArray dd=      c.getJSONArray("graphObject")
                      }
```

then json encode with dd string.